# Creating Objects for AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to create an object for AJAX. I know who to create constructors and methods for an object, but I don't know how to do it for AJAX.
My version for the constructor:

```
function Ajax(method, destination, send){
    this.method=method.toUpperCase();
    this.destination=destination;
    this.send=send;
}
var ajax=new Ajax('POST', '../info.html', true);
```

The main thing is that I don't understand how to get the results after the ReadyState==4 and the status=200. I know how to get the responseText, but I don't know how to create a method that can get the responseText and return it. Please help!

What I want to be able to do:

```
ajax.getResults();
```

Comment: You can't put a function call in the argument list of a function definition.

Comment: `function AJAX(method.toUpperCase(), ...)` isn't a valid function definition.

Comment: Where do you call `new XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: Why isn't a valid function definition?

Comment: Because the argument list has to be a list of variables. `method.toUpperCase()` isn't a variable.

Comment: That is in another method.

Comment: it's obvious you aren't being conscious of ajax being asynchronous. add a callback argument to your function that will get called on request success

Comment: Okay, so Callback the responseText?

Comment: Is the XHR a property of your AJAX class? Or is AJAX a subclass of XHR? You need to assign an `onreadystatechange` handler to the XHR, and it should set a `results` property, which `getResults()` should return.

Comment: Or, more properly, the caller of your AJAX should be able to supply a callback function that receives the results as a parameter.

Comment: What is XHR? Is that when the Ajax object is being created?

Comment: *"What I want to be able to do: `ajax.getResults();`"* Sorry, you can't effectively do that unless `ajax.getResults` accepts a callback function.